# Django URL Pattern Matching Question

Tags: regex, django

I have a problem I cant seem to figure out. Working in Django trying to get a hanlde on the URL matching . I have one that works. One that doesnt and I cannot figure out why. Hoping someone can help.

### The one that works:

```
url(r'^person/device/program/oneday/(?P<meter_id>\d+)/$', 
therm_control.Get_One_Day_Of_Current_Device_Schedule.as_view(), 
name="one-day-url"),
```

When I use this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/personview/person/device/program/oneday/149778/
```

### The one that does not:

```
url(r'^person/device/program/oneday/(?P<meter_id>\d+)/(?P<day_of_the_week>\s+)/$', 
therm_control.Get_One_Day_Of_Current_Thermostat_Schedule.as_view(), 
name="one-day-url"),
```

When I use this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/personview/person/device/program/oneday/149778/Monday/
```

They view is the same in both cases. For trying the second I add the day_of_the_week to the def get()

What I see in the debug is the 404:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/personview/person/device/program/oneday/149778/Monday/
```

I see this in the URLconf list so I know it is in the conf:

```
^personview/ ^person/device/program/oneday/(?P<meter_id>\d+)/(?P<day_of_the_week>\s+)/$ [name='one-day-url']
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\s+ will match one or more spaces, you want \w+:

```
url(r'^person/device/program/oneday/(?P<meter_id>\d+)/(?P<day_of_the_week>\w+)/$', 
    therm_control.Get_One_Day_Of_Current_Thermostat_Schedule.as_view(),
    name="one-day-url"),
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\s` means a whitespace character in a regex, so in your URLconf the day of the week has to be a sequence of whitespace characters. If you replace `\s` with `\w` it will instead look for word characters, which is what you want.